# how to fill in all text fields at once with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have a form with many text inputs and I want to fill them at once with Selenium IDE with the same text.
I want to make that with a loop like:

```
=> loop
   click | //input[@type=text] of index i
   type | //input[@type=text] of index i | someTexte
=> end
```

Comment: You want this in the IDE?

Comment: @DMart, Yes of course.

Comment: Look here for loops: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow

Answer (score -1):

may this code snippet will help (by Selenium WebDriver)

```
List<WebElement> inputs = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])"));
inputs.forEach(input -> {
    input.sendKeys("some text");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want that for the IDE, not for WebDriver.